# How to Remove ActionBar Overflow from ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

In a typical Android Activity, you would normally do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.refresh_details, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and in the XML file, you would have:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

However, when you change the activity to ActionBarActivity, the overflow menu suddenly appears and the item does not appear as an icon in the action bar. How do I restore the behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using support library attributes you need to use a custom namespace, in this example `app`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item 
        ...
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

From the [Google Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems):

> Using XML attributes from the support library
>
> Notice that the
>   showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the
>    tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by
>   the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the
>   Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace
>   as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that part.